# SELECT with different column order and distinct WHERE conditions returns more rows than total count of rows

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have following SELECT statements:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table1
```

> returns 500 rows in table (There are no rows with age = NULL)

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, occupation 
FROM table1
WHERE age <= 10
```

> returns 200 rows in table

```
SELECT occupation, last_name, first_name
FROM table1
WHERE age > 10
```

> **returns 320 rows in table**

How can be this possible? 
The numbers were chosen arbitrary but what can be the reason?
Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: What is the data type of age?  I don't actually think this is possible with numeric comparisons.  You may have oversimplified your actual situation.

Comment: Hello, it is INTEGER.

Comment: I have had this question on interview, and I couldn't explain it, what can be the reason for this behavior.

Comment: Besides, `count(*)` counts all rows, regardless of null's. `count(col)` counts non-null col values.

Comment: There should not be a difference if the data is static between the 3 queries if not static then there will be differences.

Comment: table1 is actually a view, and the age value is calculated at select time. If you wait for months until you execute query 2, perhaps 20 persons has turned 11. Lesson to be learned: never store age, store date of birth!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

table1 is actually a *view*, and the age value is calculated at select time. If you wait for months until you execute query 2, perhaps 20 persons has turned 11.

Lesson to be learned: never store age, store date of birth!

Comment: Thank you, this is good answer but why have not the order of columns in SELECT clausule  impact on evaluation of SELECT?

Comment: The column order doesn't matter. Perhaps a _red herring_ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring.)